# How do I extend a model class to another model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class

I am trying to extend a class to another class that will collect them as a list.

model:

```
public class Brand
    {
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public float Rating { get; set; }
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Postal { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        public virtual Snapshot Snapshot { get; set; }
    }
public class Snapshot
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeSent { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Html { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Unsubscribe { get; set; }
}
public class BrandSnaphotViewModel
    {
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public List<Snapshot> SnapshotItems { get; set; }

    }
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string brandGuid)
    {
        BrandSnaphotViewModel viewModel = new BrandSnaphotViewModel();
        Brand brand = GetBrand(brandGuid);
        viewModel.Brand = brand;
        List<Snapshot> snapshot = GetBrandSnapshots(brand.BrandId);
        viewModel.SnapshotItems = snapshot;

        List<BrandSnaphotViewModel> viewModelList = new List<BrandSnaphotViewModel>();
        viewModelList.Add(viewModel);

        return View(viewModelList.AsEnumerable());
    }

private Brand GetBrand(string brandGuid)
{
    Brand brand = new Brand();
    string dbConnString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnString);
    dbConn.Open();
    MySqlCommand dbCmd = new MySqlCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT *, industries.name AS industry_name FROM brands LEFT JOIN industries ON brands.industry_id = industries.industry_id WHERE brand_guid = '" + brandGuid.ToString() + "' AND private = 0 LIMIT 1";
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
    MySqlDataReader dbResult = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dbResult.Read())
    {
        brand.Guid = dbResult["brand_guid"].ToString();
        brand.BrandId = Convert.ToInt32(dbResult["brand_id"]);
        brand.Industry = dbResult["industry_name"].ToString();
    }
    dbResult.Close();
    dbConn.Close();

    return brand;
}

private List<Snapshot> GetBrandSnapshots(int brandId)
{
    string dbConnString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnString);
    dbConn.Open();
    MySqlCommand dbCmd = new MySqlCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM snapshots WHERE brand_id = " + brandId + " AND archive = 0 ORDER BY date_sent DESC";
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
    MySqlDataReader dbResult = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
    List<Snapshot> snapshots = new List<Snapshot>();
    while (dbResult.Read())
    {
        snapshots.Add(new Snapshot
        {
            SnapshotId = Convert.ToInt32(dbResult["snapshot_id"]),
            Subject = dbResult["subject"].ToString(),
            DateTimeSent = Convert.ToDateTime(dbResult["date_sent"]),
            Image = dbResult["image"].ToString(),
            Email = dbResult["email"].ToString(),
            ContentType = dbResult["content_type"].ToString(),
            Type = dbResult["type"].ToString()
        });
    }
    dbResult.Close();
    dbConn.Close();

    return snapshots;
}
```

edit
FIXED

The issue was the VIEW was not referencing the ViewModel as an IENumerable<>. FACEPALM.

```
@model IEnumerable<projectvia.ViewModels.BrandSnaphotViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @item.Brand.Guid;
    for(int i = 0; i< @item.SnapshotItems.Count; i++)
    {
        @item.SnapshotItems[i].Subject<br/>
    }
}
```

That resolved the issue.

Thank you both experts for the insights... i took both advice and came to this solution.

Comment: *Please* search for advice on avoiding SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing wrong, it is a list.

you cannot add element this way. Create object and add that object in list by calling `Add()`

do like this to add items in it:

```
List<BrandEmailList> brandSnapshotsList = new List<BrandEmailList>();
    while (dbResult.Read())
    {
        BrandEmailList brandSnapshots = new  BrandEmailList (); // create an object
        brandSnapshots.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dbResult["snapshot_id"]);
        brandSnapshots.Guid = dbResult["snapshot_guid"].ToString();
        brandSnapshots.DateTimeSent = dbResult["date_sent"];
        brandSnapshots.Subject = dbResult["subject"].ToString();
        brandSnapshots.Image = dbResult["image"];

       brandSnapshotsList.Add(brandSnapshots); // add it in list
    }
```

**EDIT:**
List is a generic thing, you don't need to create a class for it. you can just instantiate a list and add items in it.

why are you doing like that you can do it this way simply:

```
List<Snapshot> brandSnapshotsList = new List<Snapshot>();
        while (dbResult.Read())
        {
            Snapshot brandSnapshots = new  Snapshot(); // create an object
            brandSnapshots.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dbResult["snapshot_id"]);
            brandSnapshots.Guid = dbResult["snapshot_guid"].ToString();
            brandSnapshots.DateTimeSent = dbResult["date_sent"];
            brandSnapshots.Subject = dbResult["subject"].ToString();
            brandSnapshots.Image = dbResult["image"];

           brandSnapshotsList.Add(brandSnapshots); // add it in list
        }
```

Comment: it is still not recognizing the ID, Guid, etc... definition. I do not believe BrandEmailList is extending to the Snapshot Class that sets and gets these properties.

Comment: Ehsan, thanks. The intent was to use foreach in the view to return the list of ID, GUID, etc...

Comment: You can create another class for that why making it so complex

Answer (score 2):

Building on what Ehsan Sajjad did, looking at `public IEnumerator<Snapshot> BrandEmails`, i believe what you look for looks more like this:

```
public class Snapshot
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class BrandEmailList : List<Snapshot>
{
}
```

You need not even create a new type for your brand email list, you can use `List<Snapshot>` directly.

```
public ViewResult Whatever() {
    var brand = GetBrand(brandName);
    var brandSnapshots = GetBrandSnapshots();

    return View(brand, brandSnapshots);
}

private Brand GetBrand(string brandName)
{
    try 
    {
        var brand = new Brand();
        brand.Name = brandName;
        // database stuffs ...
        return brand;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private List<Snapshot> GetBrandSnapshots()
{
    // ...
    // DB stuffs -- that *really* should not be in the controller anyways.
    // ...

    var snapshots = new List<BrandEmailList>();
    while (dbResult.Read())
    {
        // object initializer syntax
        snapshots.Add(new Snapshot {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dbResult["snapshot_id"]),
        Guid = dbResult["snapshot_guid"].ToString(),
        DateTimeSent = dbResult["date_sent"],
        Subject = dbResult["subject"].ToString(),
        Image = dbResult["image"],
        });     
    }
    return snapshots
}
```

As a side note, mixing database access into controller methods can be a bad idea. It does not have to be, but it can be. Generally, fetching data from the database happens at a different "level" than serving a MVC result. MVC controller don't have the "purpose" to talk to a database, that work can/should be delegated to a dedicated type. Compare the *single responsibility principle* part of the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: Thank you, I will be moving the DB queries to the model instead. However, in the meantime, I am getting the following error: cannot convert models.snapshot to models.brandemaillist

Comment: NO! Not the model, please. Doing it in the controller is a *lot* better than in the model. You will be passing the model around quite a bit, potentially, and should not have any consumer of your model depend on database access classes. One of the reason why it should not be in the controller either. Move it into it's **own** database access type. Types are cheap! :) As for your error, you probably try to *assign* a single instance to a list-type variable, instead of *adding* it to the list. Hard to say w/o your code though.